# Best practice for a form with lots of data sources/lookup

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have a C# WinForm that has a lot of lookup data, around 40-50 different code sets needed to populate the various combo boxes. I wish I could break it up into different forms, but the data needs to be together on this one form.

I'm using Entity Framework to model the data, so I'm not sure what the best practice would be to load all these data sources. I'm worried that if I load all the data sources at once, there will be a significant performance hit...so I suppose the other option would be on-demand loading (loading code sets only if editing is needed), but that would add a lot of code complexity (I'd need to add event handlers to each combobox).

Also, is it better performance wise to create Binding Sources, or just populate the Data Source directly using a LINQ query.

Comment: There is a EF concept "deferred execution". If you have many Linq2EF queries as a datasource, they are not executing the DB query at startup, but rather when it needed (for example when the combo opened)

Comment: I thought though that in order to bind a combobox to a LINQ query, I have to Enumerate it with a ToList(), otherwise I get a runtime error complaining that I cannot bind to a DBQuery...what you are saying would be great, perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: You don't have to use ToList() to enumerate, combobox will enumerate your query when you assign it to the datasource property. So my first comment is wrong, if you assign a query for example in form load event, DB query is executed, sorry...

comboBox1.DataSource = ctx.Employees.Where(en => en.TitleOfCourtesy == "Mr.");
This is valid, but not deferred.

Comment: Ok so with that in mind, is it better to populate the datasources on demand, as opposed to loading all 40-50 when the form loads?

Comment: If you worried about performance do not set datasource property on your form Load event, but later as you said on-demand.